# Using requests package to make request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an application (spark based service), which when starts..works like following.

At `localhost:9000`

if I do `nc -lk localhost 9000` 
and then start entering the text.. it takes the text entered in terminal as an input and do a simple wordcount computation on it.
how do i use the `requests` library to programmatically send the text, instead of manually writing them in the terminal.

Not sure if my question is making sense..

Comment: `requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:9000", data="hello world")`

Comment: Does this application provide an HTTP server or just a raw TCP/IP server? `requests` won't let you send raw TCP/IP requests without  adjoining HTTP headers, and TCP/IP servers won't know what to do with HTTP headers. @PadraicCunningham's will work only if the application supports HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

requests is a HTTP request library, while Spark's wordcount example provides a raw socket server, so no, requests is not the right package to communicate with your Spark app.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that, in such an event, a raw socket library such as Python's native [`socket`](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html) library will suffice.